# 15 tongue steel drum sheet music symbol meanings

Tags: sheet-music, percussion

The music has numbers ( 1 or sometimes more)that are underscored _ once and sometimes twice.  Meaning??
Phrase marks?
Brackets connecting a group of numbers?

[image: Sheet Music Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found an example of what you are describing, and will answer based on that. Let us know if this is what you meant. [image: Tongue drum notation example]

Example from here: https://www.mymusicsheet.com/aprilyangkalimba/22285

- Numbers: Scale degrees. The first note in the scale is 1, the next note is 2, and so on. The numbers may be marked on your drum. The numbering system is based on a particular scale, if the drum uses a different scale than the notation was written for the notes may be off.
- Dot above or below: One octave higher (above) or lower (below).
- Underline: The note duration is half of the notes without an underline. The normal duration is one note per beat (also called a quarter note in 4/4), an underline is two notes per beat (also called an 8th note).
- Double underline: The note duration is half of a single underline. So four notes per beat, aka 16th notes.

[image: Tie example]

- Curved line: This is called a tie, it means that although the number is printed twice it is to be played as one note with a longer duration. How long depends on the length of the tie, in this case the note lasts for two beats.

[image: Dotted number example]

- Dot after the number: Note duration is 50% longer. The dot on the right hand side of the first note here means that it lasts for one and a half beat. The next note has an underline (8th note/lasts half a beat), and by the third note we are back to one note per beat again.

Comment: This is standard Chinese notation.